# Why is Rails (with Nginx/Passenger via Ansible) unable to see my RAILS_MASTER_KEY environment variable?

Tags: ansible, nginx, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails

I'm writing Ansible playbooks to provision an Ubuntu 18.04 server.

I want to provision the server for a Rails application using Passenger and Nginx. I used [geerlingguy.passenger](https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/passenger) from Ansible Galaxy to configure Passenger and Nginx.

In addition, I used [zzet.rbenv](https://galaxy.ansible.com/zzet/rbenv) to install ruby 2.5.3.

The Ansible playbooks seem to have executed correctly, and when I log into the server via SSH, everything seems to be working (rbenv is on the path, `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable is defined).

Deployment of my application via Capistrano also appears to run successfully.

However, when I attempt to visit the landing page, I get a Passenger error: "Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server."

Looking in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, I see:

```
Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to /var/www/releases/20191230212823/config/master.key or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'].
```

I'm not sure why the above error is happening, because I've already configured a persistent environment variable using the [weareinteractive.environment](https://galaxy.ansible.com/weareinteractive/environment) role.

Inspecting /etc/environment confirms that RAILS_MASTER_KEY is defined, and I can see if it I log in manually as my 'deploy' user. However, `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` shows that the default user is `www-data`:

```
user www-data;
```

I think this should be fine, because the environment variables are configured in a way that is not associated with a user account. So, why does Rails fail to see this environment variable even though I see it when I log in via SSH?

I'm able to execute the following command on the server and see the contents of the encrypted credentials file:

```
RAILS_ENV=production EDITOR=vim bundle exec rails credentials:edit
```

So what is going wrong when Nginx/Passenger launch Rails?

Edit: It seems like Passenger/Nginx do not load environment variables from /etc/environment, which mostly explains my problem. I'm trying to figure out the appropriate way to configure environment variables for Passenger using Ansible now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause: environment variables from `/etc/environment` are not passed to Passenger. The standard method seems to be [passenger_env_var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080656/where-to-put-environment-variables-when-using-nginx-and-passenger-on-ubuntu/10080827) in your nginx config as suggested by user **joshaidan**.